# Selecting the non-duplicate elements in the DataTable

Tags: vb.net

I want to choose non-duplicate elements in DataTable

Where DataTable contains data as follows

TABLE A
COLUMN A

AM1
AM5
AM6
AM5
AM1
AM1
AM1

Where the final output is datatable= AM6

MY CODE

```
Public Function RemoveDuplicateRowsG(ByVal dTable As DataTable) As DataTable

     For intI = dTable.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
         For intJ = intI - 1 To 0 Step -1
             If dTable.Rows(intI)(0) = dTable.Rows(intJ)(0) Then
                 dTable.Rows.RemoveAt(intI)
                 dTable.Rows.RemoveAt(intJ)
                 Exit For
             End If
         Next
     Next
     dTable.AcceptChanges()
     Return dTable
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you iterate the datatable first and select the row(s) which contain the value only once, put it inside a new datatable and return the newly created datatable.

```
Dim dtToReturn As New DataTable 

For Each row As DataRow in dTable.Rows
  'Select all rows from original datatable with the same value
  Dim datarow() As DataRow = dTable.Select("COLUMN A = " & row.Item(0))
  'Insert to the new datatable if returned datarow collection only has 1 row
  If datarow.Count = 1 Then
    dtToReturn.Rows.Add(datarow)
  End If
Next

Return dtToReturn
```